# When inner elements "leak" their margins, how can I get the outer element's correct height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Imagine this document:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Leak</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="main">
     <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li class="b">b</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li class="b">b</li>
        <li>a</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
     <div>Footer</div>
     <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: red"/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Open it in chrome of firebug and you will see, that there is some kind of unexplained margin-top on the body element. It comes from the ul element, two levels deeper. I think this is kind of an eery behavior, but I am certain those wc3 guys who came up with that have had their good reasons.

But how, can I get to that in javascript? I need to set the #main div's height to $(window).height() - $('#footer').height(), so it that #footer is always at the bottom.

```
$('#main').height($(window).height() - $('#footer').height())
```

But this leaves a scrollbar, because of this space on top. Try removing the ul and everything is as expected. How can I account for this? This is for a plugin, so I cannot account for special markup, this should "just work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by setting "overflow: auto" to the stretched div, in this case #main. It is not a javascript solution, but is somewhat acceptable. I can let the user decide if this fix should be applied or he can take care of this elsewise.

Answer (score 0):

no, the margin comes from the body element. Every browser generates this by default. Just add body: margin: 0; padding: 0; to get rid of it.

Comment: Im very confused by your question actually.I also see no scrollbar.

Comment: The body has margins which are easy to account for. Open the example in the browser and you will see, that there is an additional margin, leaking out of #main, coming from the ul element.

Comment: so are you trying to get rid of that? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: No, I do not want to get rid of it. The question is as stated above. I need to know how much overlap there is, not remove it.
And you will see a scrollbar upon running the javascript one-liner, I am pretty certain. At least I hope so, as this would mean consistent behavior between browsers...

Comment: the only way you're going to know this is by setting it yourself. All browsers generate a different margin.

Comment: simply set your desired margin with JavaScript instead of using actual css then go from there.

Comment: I need to measure the overlap and reduce #main's height by it.

Comment: right. The only way you can measure the overlap is by setting a margin to override the browsers.

Comment: I'm also not getting the scrollbar you're getting in any browser.

Comment: Interesting, maybe a platform bug? Which platfom are you on? I tried in chrome and firefox on mac.

Comment: can you post your complete code with all the jQuery applied? I'm trying to apply the jQuery but now sure if it's running correctly. Thanks.lets move this to chat

Comment: And how exactly would you, by setting the margin of all ul, p, hn, ... elements, get to the overlap? You have no prior knowledge of what is within #main, it could be anything and any number of it in any position.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5507/discussion-between-jan-limpens-and-michael-rader)

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a reset css, this is common practice to deal with browser inconsistencies. Some browsers apply a default padding, others apply a default margin.

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the style of the page, this would be too intrusive.